# maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded php

Tags: php

When I run my script I receive the following error before processing all rows of data.

> maximum execution time of 30 seconds
>   exceeded

After researching the problem, I *should* be able to extend the max_execution_time time which *should* resolve the problem.

But being in my PHP programming infancy I would like to know if there is a more optimal way of doing my script below, so I do not have to rely on "get out of jail cards".

The script is:

1 Taking a CSV file

2 Cherry picking some columns

3 Trying to insert 10k rows of CSV data into a my SQL table

In my head I think I should be able to insert in chunks, but that is so far beyond my skillset I do not even know how to write one line :\

Many thanks in advance

```
<?php
function processCSV()
{
    global $uploadFile;
    include 'dbConnection.inc.php';
    dbConnection("xx","xx","xx");
    $rowCounter = 0;
    $loadLocationCsvUrl = fopen($uploadFile,"r");   
    if ($loadLocationCsvUrl <> false)
    {
        while ($locationFile = fgetcsv($loadLocationCsvUrl, ','))
        {
            $officeId = $locationFile[2];
            $country = $locationFile[9];
            $country = trim($country);
            $country = htmlspecialchars($country);
            $open = $locationFile[4];
            $open = trim($open);
            $open = htmlspecialchars($open);
            $insString = "insert into countrytable set officeId='$officeId', countryname='$country', status='$open'";
                switch($country)
                {
                    case $country <> 'Country':
                        if (!mysql_query($insString))
                        {
                            echo "<p>error " . mysql_error() . "</p>";    
                        }
                        break;
                }
            $rowCounter++;
        }
        echo "$rowCounter inserted.";
    }
    fclose($loadLocationCsvUrl);
}
processCSV();
?>
```

Comment: Do you need to do this once or do you insert 10k rows in the database every now and then?

Comment: Also, are you running this through a web server, i.e. are you calling the page from a browser, or are you running it via command line?

Comment: @Salman A > It will probably be done 2 or 3 times a month

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, in 2011 you do not use mysql_query. You use mysqli or PDO and prepared statements. Then you do not need to figure out how to escape strings for SQL. You used `htmlspecialchars` which is totally wrong for this purpose. Next, you could use a transaction to speed up many inserts. MySQL also supports multiple interests.

But the best bet would be to use the CSV storage engine. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/csv-storage-engine.html read here. You can instantly load everything into SQL and then manipulate there as you wish. The article also shows the `load data infile` command.

Comment: Thank you I have never heard of the "CSV storage engine" I will research out to implement it, sorry for my poor code I am still new to all of this and I have been readin' and old book.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could create a single query like this.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO countrytable (officeId, countryname, status) VALUES ";
$entries = array();
while ($locationFile = fgetcsv($loadLocationCsvUrl, ',')) {
    // your code
    $entries[] = "('$officeId', '$country', '$open')";
}

$query .= implode(', ', $enties);
mysql_query($query);
```

But this depends on how long your query will be and what the server limit is set to.

But as you can read in other posts, there are better way for your requirements. But I thougt I should share a way you did thought about.

Comment: I was about to say the same. I recently imported 1.3GB of data in ~3 minutes into mysql from a mysqldump file. 10k records should not be a problem with a multiple insert statement but still you should break it down into batches of say 500 rows per insert.

Comment: Thank you this has made a material difference

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling the following function before inserting. This will set the time limit to unlimited instead of the 30 sec default time.

`set_time_limit( 0 );`

Comment: The question was how to resolve the problem without changing the time limit.